# Weird behaviour from GUI apps in windows

Tags: windows, windows-10

My computer is behaving weird when resizing, minimizing, or maximizing apps. This is what happens when I resize or maximize a window:

[image]

I don't know what is happening. It seems that when I make a window bigger, the borderlines from smaller window don't hide and just draws new borders next to them. Also, there is a similar problem when I move the cursor in notepad:

[image]

There is the same problem again after maximizing notepad but notice how cursor lines are copied as I moved the cursor with left and right arrows. (I moved the cursor after maximizing so it's not related to that)

Another problem is the black background (in errors):
[image]
[image]
Another related problem: In the second picture, the yes/no buttons don't have any border.

What's the problem here? How can I solve it? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you updated your graphics card drivers?

Comment: @LPChip my graphic card driver is the official one. Also I haven't done anything before this problem occured and nothing is changed. Maybe updating graphics card drivers could help but sometimes after installing official drivers for some devices, I tried updating them and windows found a wrong driver for them and I had to restore it and as nothing is changed before this problem, I don't think it's related to drivers.

Comment: Software can become corrupt. For example the driver can be installed on a section on the harddrive which now has a bad sector. A corrupted driver would show this kind of symptoms. Reinstalling the driver is a necessary step to rule this out. Otherwise installing a different version of the driver may be the trick, if the driver was updated by windows and contains a bug (less likely).

Comment: @LPChip Ok, I'll try that to see if the problem persists.

Comment: press Ctrl+Win+Shift+B to see. Most of the time it'll solve the issue until the graphics driver is updated

Comment: @phuclv Nope, it doesn't solve my problem. After pressing these keys, my screen goes blacks, and when it turns on again nothing is being changed.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest to update and reinstall the graphics device driver.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028443/windows-10-update-drivers

If that doesn't work, one of the possible reasons why you’re experiencing this issue is system file corruption.
Creating a Test User Profile. This is for us to know if the issue is not with your existing User Profile. To create a user profile, follow these steps:

Go to Settings-Click Accounts-Select Family & other people-Select the Add someone else to this PC tab-Name the user as Test-Set up a password-Sign in as Test user.
Check if you’re experiencing the same issue.

Also, change your current theme and then this problem may be solved.